# how to load in angularJS page with node

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

I am working on a single page web app with node/angular and jade. I am fairly new to angular, and I wanted to know what I have to do with my app.js file so that my first page template loads from my angular file rather than from my jade template.

I structured my files as such:

```
public/
index.html
   javascript/
   img/
   stylesheets/
routes/
   index.js
views/
   partials/
       a.jade
       b.jade   
app.js
```

This is what my app.js looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser('cookies monster')); // Cookie secret

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

/*
 * Views
 */
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/a', routes.a);
app.get('/b', routes.b);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

My index.js looks like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Test Application' });
};

// View A
exports.a = function(req, res) {
    res.render('partials/a', { layout: false, test: 'LOL' });
};

// View B
exports.b = function(req, res) {
res.render('partials/b', { layout: false, test: 'YOLO' });
};
```

When I run this, It does not use the index.html as the first page. How would I go about doing so, so that the initial page template is actually the index.html? I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the actual index.html file from your router.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    return res.sendfile(app.get('public') + '/index.html');
});
```

I should note that I also put `app.set('public', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));` inside app.js for easy access to the public directory.

Comment: should I do this instead of app.get('/', routes.index), or after it?